# Is it possible to test my iPhone application on iOS 7.1.2 and Xcode version is 6.1.1 without developer program

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

These days I'm making an application for iOS.
I made one application and I want to test it on my device. But I don't want to pay for the developer program. (I have a mind to pay the developer program in future.)
my device iOS version is 7.1.2 and my Xcode version is 6.1.1
And the device is jailbreaked.

Please tell me how to test an application on the device without the developer program.

Answer (score -1):

You should be fine...just make sure your build target is 7.1.2 under Project Settings.

Comment: if you aren't a developer then you can't provision a device... so you can't test on a device.

Comment: He already said the phone was jailbroken... so he wants to know **how to use Xcode or some other app to install an app to a jailbroken iPhone**.

Comment: Downvotes? You can definitely do this on a jailbroken device.